# How do I run a SVN post-commit script as root?

Tags: shell, script, sudo

I have a SVN repository server that runs under the `repository` user, and I want to run a script after every post-commit action.

I therefore wrote a shell script that runs from the hook after every commit, and it needs to be run under `root`. This is why I used `sudo` in the script, but it didn't work.

Is there any way to run the script as `root`?

```
sudo su
echo "password"
svn export --force file:///home/repository/trunk/ /home/memarexweb/public_html/devel/
chmod -R 777 /home/memarexweb/public_html/devel/
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `sudoers` file to allow running certain commands without a password.

It's best to split your post-commit script into two parts, one of which will be run through `sudo`.

- `/etc/sudoers`:

  ```
  loqman    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/svn-postcommit-export
  ```
- Your post-commit hook:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  sudo /usr/local/bin/svn-postcommit-export
  ```
- `/usr/local/bin/svn-postcommit-export`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  svn export --force file:///home/repository/trunk/ /home/memarexweb/public_html/devel/
  chmod -R 777 /home/memarexweb/public_html/devel/
  ```

  (You can choose any name and put the script anywhere; I just suggested `svn-postcommit-export` as an example, and `/usr/local/bin` as a common location.)

---

### Now why the hell did it not work

You might be thinking that everything in a script is being run exactly as if entered by you with keyboard. This is not the case. The interpreter (*sh*) runs each command separately, waits for it to finish, then runs the next one.

There also are rules on how input and output is handled – programs read their input from 'stdin' – *not* from your script – and write output to 'stdout'<sup>0</sup>. When you run your script in a terminal window<sup>1</sup>, its 'stdin' and 'stdout' will be attached to your keyboard and that terminal window, and this will be inherited by all commands: `su`<sup>2</sup> doesn't know what the rest of your script looks like; instead it expects commands to be entered from 'stdin' – in this case, your keyboard. Similarly, `echo "password"` will output the password to 'stdout' (your terminal window), not to `sudo`.

You can attach one process' output to another's input by using pipes; for example:

```
echo "svn export ..." | su
```

- This is a *bad* way of running commands by `su`; used here only as an example. For normal usage, `su -c 'command'` or `sudo command` are better.
- Before you try to `echo password | sudo`: **don't waste your time.** Most programs, including `sudo` and `su`, will explicitly read passwords from your terminal, not from stdin. In the case of `sudo`, you can turn off the password requirement by editing /etc/sudoers as above.

---

<sup>0</sup> 'stderr' omitted for simplicity, as it works the same way as 'stdout' in most cases.

<sup>1</sup> When the script is ran by `svn`'s post-commit, it will receive `/dev/null` as its stdin (and probably stdout).

<sup>2</sup> Simplified. In reality, `su` itself doesn't read commands, it starts a shell process (for example, `sh` or `bash`) which does the job.